# Why does mapping over a DataFrame using a case class fail with "Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset"?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have already imported `spark.implicits._` But still I get error

> Error:(27, 33) Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset.  Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._  Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases.

I have a case class like:

```
case class User(name: String, dept: String)
```

and I am converting Dataframe to dataset using:

```
val ds = df.map { row=> User(row.getString(0), row.getString(1) }
```

or

```
val ds = df.as[User]
```

Also, when I am trying the same code in `Spark-shell` I get no error, only when I run it through IntelliJ or submit the job I get this error.

Any reasons why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moving declaration of case class out of scope did the trick!

Code structure will then be like:

```
package main.scala.UserAnalytics

// case class *outside* the main object
case class User(name: string, dept: String)

object UserAnalytics extends App {
    ...
    ds = df.map { row => User(row.getString(0), row.getString(1)) }
}
```